# For F$[x]/\langle f(x)\rangle$, is it ALWAYS true that if $f(x)$ is reducible in F$[x]$, then it is NOT a field?

Tags: abstract-algebra

For F$[x]/\langle f(x)\rangle$, is it ALWAYS true that if $f(x)$ is reducible in F$[x]$, then it is NOT a field?

I know if $f(x)$ is irreducible then it is a field. Not sure if it works the other way round... Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $f=g\cdot h$. Then $g,h$ are not zero in the quotient, but their product...?

Comment: I didn't actually get what you were saying... If they are non-zero (you meant non-constant?) in the quotient, neither should their product? Then, neither $g$ nor $h$ is in ideal $I=\langle f(x) \rangle$? So by definition, $I$ is not prime and thus F$[x]/I$ is not integral domain --> not field?

Comment: @user113255 It is simpler. Let $a$ be the class of $g$ in the quotient, and $b$ the class of $h$ in the quotient. You have $a,b\ne0$ but $ab$ is the class of $f$, which is $0$. So, the quotient has zero divisors.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's always true. For if $f = g h$ with $g, h$ non-constant polynomials, then in the quotient ring $F[x]/(f)$, we get $0 = \overline f = \overline g \overline h$. Because $g, h$ themselves are non-constant polynomials and of degree less than that of $f$, their residue classes $\overline g, \overline h$ are non-zero, making them zero-divisors. Consequently, $F[x]/(f)$ is not an integral domain, so surely not a field.